# with 1.4.1RC4 seeing error for <Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder">

Tags: karate

Seeing the following error when running tests locally in VS Code

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:3.1.0:java (default-cli) @ DP-API ---
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

This is currently preventing logs from showing in the console and also seems to have an effect on reporting as no request/response or logs are being returned, just the steps completed.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with VS Code, and sounds like some library conflicts in your Maven project. Typically it can be resolved by doing `exclusions` in Maven or forcing the version of one of the dependencies. Using the ["fat jar"](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#karate-core-fat-jar) can help. Also see tips here: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-examples/blob/main/database/README.md#using-the-shaded-jar

If you can replicate this in a simple starter project, then it can be fixed.

Comment: Had to add the following to our pom, to fix the issue
`<dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>`